How does decoherence work in Everettian quantum mechanics when the observer has a limited amount of memory?
First of all, please forgive me for the confusing way I'm asking this question, I'm not quite sure how to articulate it aside from an unrealistic thought experiment. I'm trying to understand how decoherence works when there are bounds on the maximum amount of information that subsystems can store. If you can suggest a better way to ask the question, I'll accept that as an answer.
Suppose I'm a human observer and I'm trying to make a prediction about what I would see if I were living in a universe where Everettian ("many worlds") quantum mechanics is true.
There must be some limit to the amount of classical information that my brain can store in all the degrees of freedom of all the particles that make it up. That number of bits will be astronomically large, but let's call it N bits.
Now suppose I prepare 1000N qubits in the state $\|+ \rangle$ in my lab. I measure them all, the results of the measurements decohere into the environment, I see all of the measurement results, and I write all 1000N bits onto a hard drive.
The hard drive is capable of storing all $1000N$ bits, but my brain is not, since it can only store $N$ bits in all its degrees of freedom. My brain can be in any of $2^N$ classical states, but the measurement I just did created $2^{1000N}$ "worlds." That means that on average, for each classical brain state, there are $2^{1000N}/2^N = 2^{999N}$ "worlds" in which I find myself in that particular brain state.
Mathematically, we have three registers: (a) the $\|+\rangle$ qubits that were measured, (b) my brain state, and (c) the hard drive (initialized to all zeroes). The state before the measurement is,
$\sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{1000N}} \|x\rangle \|B\rangle \|0000.....\rangle$,
where $B$ is my classical brain state just before the measurement.
After the measurement, we have,
$\sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{1000N}} \|x\rangle \|B(x)\rangle \|x\rangle$,
where now the measurement results have been written to the hard drive, and my brain state has become $B(x)$, which is a function of my prior brain state and the measurement results (which includes all the ways the measurements have decohered into my brain's degrees of freedom).
But $B(x)$ is a function whose domain has a size of $1000N$ bits, while its range has a size of only $N$ bits, so there must be collisions in the second register. We can rewrite the state as,
$\sum_{b \in \{0,1\}^N} \sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{1000N} \| b = B(x)} \|x\rangle \|b\rangle \|x \rangle$.
If I find myself in brain state $\|C\rangle$, we can model that by post-selecting the second register,
$\sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{1000N} \| C = B(x)} \|x\rangle \|C\rangle \|x \rangle$,
and moving my brain state to the front,
$\|C\rangle \sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{1000N} \| C = B(x)} \|x\rangle \|x \rangle$,
showing that from my point of view, being in brain state $\|C\rangle$, the rest of the state is still in a superposition. This means that if I were to read the hard drive again, showing all of the values on a monitor, I would likely see different values than I did originally when I made the measurements, as long as both measurement outcomes would have lead to the same brain state $\|C\rangle$.
Is this what would actually happen in Everettian quantum mechanics? My previous understanding of Everettian QM was that "worlds" would permanently diverge due to decoherence, but it looks like here that they don't, and it's due to the limited amount of information my brain can store. In other words, distinct worlds can "decohere" in such a way that there are collisions within my brain state, so that from my perspective, the rest of the universe remains in a superposition.
I find this interesting from a cryptography perspective since if $H$ is a secure hash function, I should not be able to find an $x \neq x'$ such that $H(x) = H(x')$, yet if I calculated $H(x)$ and remembered it when I first made the measurements, and then calculated $H(x')$ when reading the hard drive's contents again, it must be the case that $H(x) = H(x')$, but I would have observed two different $x$ and $x'$ that have the same hashes. I'd never be able to actually write down the collision, but I would have observed it.
Is this really what would happen, or have I made some error? Does Everettian QM imply that the whole universe is likely to be in a superposition relative to the state of any subsystem that can only store a bounded amount of information?

Most of the premises in this questions are problematic, and definitely not mainstream physics: implication of observer consciousness in decoherence, the very idea of a "brain state", conflation between QM and information theory, and the idea that the Everettian interpretation of QM may imply something that QM proper would not

The substance of the question is about how decoherence works when there isn't enough information storage capacity. The reason it is asked in the context of the Everett interpretation is that is impossible to even frame questions about what is happening in reality in the Copenhagen or statistical interpretations, which deny that there is any account of what is happening in reality in quantum theory. There is plenty of material in journals about the Everett interpretation so claims that it isn't mainstream is false.

The amount of information that can be physically stored in a system is bounded by the kinds of interactions it undergoes https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.23.287 and in the real world no system gets close to those bounds except in extreme situations like black holes at which point whether you will decohere or not isn't your main problem.

This question should be reopened. It is an operational question about what would be observed according to a particular mainstream interpretation of quantum mechanics, in a scenario where different interpretations give different predictions. Although it's not quite testable (the observer necessarily forgets the outcome of the experiment), it is still well-posed and within the realm of mainstream quantum foundations research. It's not an 'unpublished, personal theory' and is therefore not off-topic for that reason. I also disagree that the essence of the question is about consciousness.

I agree with user34722; part of my motivation, which I regret not stating explicitly in the question, was to better understand an operational (although incommunicable) difference between the Everettian interpretation and other interpretations such as objective-collapse models. My question is probably better stated without referencing consciousness at all, and instead just asking how a subsystem with bounded memory would evolve in an Everettian universe, but unfortunately I lacked the skills to articulate it properly.

I'm especially interested in the following: modeling my scenario using finite registers of qubits leads to the conclusion that I see different bits the next time I read the measurements from the hard drive. But does that also apply for real quantum mechanics, such as what Everett used in his thesis? In other words, is it the case that the qubit-register approximation is totally wrong here, and actually decoherence works as it should when everything is real, continuous, infinite-dimensional, quantum mechanics?

Your math is correct. You're asking for a philosophical interpretation that Everettian QM can't give you.
All that Everettian QM says is that if
$|\text{brain state 1}\rangle\otimes|\text{rest of world A}\rangle$ evolves into $|\text{brain state 2}\rangle\otimes|\text{rest of world A}\rangle$ and
$|\text{brain state 1}\rangle\otimes|\text{rest of world B}\rangle$ evolves into $|\text{brain state 2}\rangle\otimes|\text{rest of world B}\rangle$,
then by linearity
$|\text{brain state 1}\rangle\otimes\big(α|\text{rest of world A}\rangle + β|\text{rest of world B}\rangle\big)$ evolves into $|\text{brain state 2}\rangle\otimes\big(α|\text{rest of world A}\rangle + β|\text{rest of world B}\rangle\big)$.
This is not a trivial statement since in other interpretations of QM there are nonlinear processes at work.
You're asking whether brain state 2 is "shared" between the worlds in such a way that the "you" it represents could experience world A before entering state 2 and world B after. You would need a physical theory of consciousness to answer that. From the perspective of quantum mechanics, it's meaningless. The state is just a vector; you might as well ask whether the number 2 in this world is the same as the number 2 in another world, or just a copy of it. I factored the states for conciseness, but if I'd multiplied them out they would be the same physical states, at least as far as Everettian QM and all known physics is concerned.
Hash functions are not secure against this much parallelism. If you use quantum randomness to pick two distinct strings from a set of $2^{256}+1$ strings and compute their SHA-256 hashes, then by the pigeonhole principle at least one copy of you will observe a hash collision that you can write down. This method of finding collisions only requires $2^{255}(2^{256}+1)$ worlds, which is much less than $2^N$.

Yeah, I think my question would be better posed without bringing consciousness into it, but I couldn't think of a better way to put it. I'm open to suggestions there. On the hash function part, the difference is that in the scenario of my question, almost all copies of me observe a collision. Say $N=2^{64}$, then with near certainty I observe a SHA256 collision by doing only $1000 \cdot 2^{64}$ operations, when it should take at least $2^{128}$ operations to find a collision.

This isn't really answering the original question. On the philosophy side, we can just make the mild assumption that brain states map to conscious experiences many-to-one and then ask what many-worlds says about collapse in this case.

In the unrealistic scenario of perfect isolation from the rest of the universe, the smaller system cannot collapse the larger system because it cannot be maximally entangled with it. But if anything else in the universe interacts with the bits during the measurement process or while they are stored in the scientist's brain, the bits will collapse. In fact the scientist forgetting the outcome of previous measurements is likely a dissipative process, and thus leads to entanglement with the rest of the universe. See 'Landauer's principle.'

@user34722 I'm sorry but I don't understand any of your objections. "[assume] brain states map to conscious experiences many-to-one and then ask what many-worlds says about collapse in this case" – many-worlds is just Schrödinger evolution; it won't say anything about consciousness or collapse. "the smaller system cannot collapse the larger system" – what systems? Are you saying the conscious states are extra DOF? Then they're just more brain states. "leads to entanglement with the rest of the universe" – brain states are always entangled with the rest of the universe in many-worlds.
